# How to know when an array pointer has reached the end where's there are no items

Tags: php, arrays

I'm now using `end()` to get the last array item, but I don't want this.

I want to know when there are no items and start from the beginning of the array.

```
$current = $_SESSION['current_song'];
$song_array = explode(',', $_SESSION['song_array']);
$nextkey = array_search($current, $song_array) + 1;
$last_song = end($song_array);

if ($nextkey == count($song_array)){ 
    $nextkey == 0;
}

$next = $song_array[$nextkey];
if ($next == $last_song){
    $sid = $song_array[0];
} else {
    $sid = $next;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while($element = current($song_array)){
   // for every item, until we reach the end of the array
   // print_r($element) and see what you have...

   // when finished, move to next element
   next($song_array);
}

// reset pointer to the beginning, if you like
reset($song_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like that might suit your need if you need to call it multiple times:

```php
// move pointer to next song
function findnext(&$song_array, $current)
{
    do {
        if (false === next($song_array)) {
            reset($song_array);
        }
    } while (current($song_array) != $current);

    // get next item, rewinding the array if needed
    return next($song_array) ?: reset($song_array);
}

$next = findnext($song_array, $current);
```